# MomentJS: What day is it for a given timezone

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I am using [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) and [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/).

I want to get a day output using timezone input

For example:

```
momenttz = require('moment-timezone');
var day = momenttz.tz('Asia/Anadyr').format('dd');
```

Should give 'Sat' as I write this question but gives me 'Fri'.

Comment: I get Sa, seems to works fine ..

Comment: Same piece of code? I still get Fri @Alexander Thanks

Comment: yes, http://prntscr.com/5l30bj

Comment: Thanks again, whats your timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the way I used the momenttz module

Should be

```
var day = momenttz().tz('Asia/Anadyr').format('dd');
```